# Can a regular grammar be ambiguous?

Tags: automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar

An *ambiguous grammar* is a context-free grammar for which there exists a string that has more than one leftmost derivation, while an unambiguous grammar is a context-free grammar for which every valid string has a unique leftmost derivation.

A *regular grammar* is a mathematical object, $G$, with four components, $G = (N, \Sigma, P, S)$, where

- $N$ is a nonempty, finite set of *nonterminal symbols*,
- $\Sigma$ is a finite set of *terminal symbols*, or alphabet, symbols,
- $P$ is a set of *grammar rules*, each of one having one of the forms:

  - $A \rightarrow aB$
  - $A \rightarrow a$
  - $A \rightarrow \varepsilon$
    for $A, B \in N$, $a \in Σ$, and $\varepsilon$ the empty string, and
- $S ∈ N$ is the *start symbol*.

Now the question is: Can a regular grammar also be ambiguous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every regular grammar which contains a rule of the form $A \rightarrow aB$ (reachable from the start symbol) has an equivalent ambiguous regular grammar. Just take a new non-terminal symbol, $D$, add the rule $A \rightarrow aD$, and for each rule with $B$ as the left symbol add a new rule obtained by replacing each $B$ in that rule with $D$.

For example, the following regular grammar is unambiguous:

$$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow aS \mid bA \\
A &\rightarrow bA \mid aB \mid \varepsilon \\
B &\rightarrow aB \mid \varepsilon
\end{align}$$

Taking the rule $A \rightarrow aB$ we construct an equivalent ambiguous regular grammar as follows:
$$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow aS \mid bA \\
A &\rightarrow bA \mid aB \mid aD \mid \varepsilon \\
B &\rightarrow aB \mid \varepsilon \\
D &\rightarrow aD \mid \varepsilon
\end{align}$$

Then the string $ba$ has the following two leftmost derivations:

- $S \rightarrow bA \rightarrow baB \rightarrow ba \varepsilon = ba$
- $S \rightarrow bA \rightarrow baD \rightarrow ba \varepsilon = ba$

Answer (score 0):

See this:
S --> aA|aB
A --> λ
B --> λ
It is a right-regular grammer with ambiguity as 'a' can be printed by either following aA from S or aB from S.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at this naive example,

$S→A | B$

$A→λ$

$B→λ$

In this example, the string $λ$ can be printed in two ways, which gives rise to ambiguity.

Comment: Please read this: [How to write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656).

Answer (score -2):

We know from Chomsky's Heirarchy of Languages that every regular language is also a context free language.

We also know every regular language is also a regular grammar.

Therefore, every regular grammar is also a context free grammar. Since CFGs can be abmbiguous, therefore by logic, some regular grammars can be ambiguous. (not ALL but there exists, in this case).

Comment: It's not logical

Comment: Just because you don't understand what i wrote, does not mean its not logical. Please don't comment nonesense. Thanks.

Comment: Im sorry but that some cfg are ambiguous do not implies that the subset of regular language is ambiguous : "Therefore by logic" is wrong. Take for instance "primes are odd", "some odd numbers are divisible by 9" don't imply "some primes are divisible by 9".